# How to convert image to binary in Swift

Tags: swift

I created an app to take an image and convert this image to binary and send to server. I take the image but I can't convert it.

I use this code :

```
func cameraa(){
    let picker = UIImagePickerController()
    picker.delegate = self
    picker.sourceType = .Camera
    presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}


func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    ImageDisplay.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage;dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}



@IBAction func Encode(sender: UIButton) {

    var imageEncode = ImageDisplay.image

    let image : UIImage = UIImage(imageEncode)
    let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)

    print(imageData)
```

My error in parse image(imageEncode) to (let image : UIImage = UIImage(imageEncode))

Comment: `imageData` is already a binary representation of your image. What is your problem?

Comment: can i send this binary to server as multipart ?

Comment: ImageDisplay.image.pngData()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `ImageDisplay.image` is already a `UIImage`. So you needn't to convert it to `UIImage` again. Just do that:

```
let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(ImageDisplay.image)

print(imageData)
```

Comment: let imgTest = UIImage.init(named: "logo.png")
let imageData = imgTest!.pngData()


Latest Code

Comment: let img = UIImage(named: "response")
                let data = img?.pngData() worked for me! just to share.